# Из консоли вводится предложение. Определить ошибся ли автор в написании "Жи/Ши пиши с буквой и"

Tags: java, массивы, split

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите строку:");
        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        String zhiWrong = "жы";
        String shiWrong = "шы";
        String zhiRight = "жи";
        String shiRight = "ши";

        str = str.toLowerCase();

        String[] words = str.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            //words = str.split(" ");
            System.out.println(words[i]);
            if (words[i].contains(zhiRight) | words[i].contains(shiRight)) {
                System.out.println("Правильно!");
            } else if (words[i].contains(zhiWrong) | words[i].contains(shiWrong)) {
                System.out.println("Неправильно! Жи/Ши пиши с буквой 'и'");
            } else
                System.out.println("Для этого слова правило не применяется");
        }
    }
}
```

Поменял. Но теперь выходит: 
Введите строку:
жыраф жывет в африке
жыраф
Неправильно! Жи/Ши пиши с буквой 'и'
жывет
Неправильно! Жи/Ши пиши с буквой 'и'
в
Для этого слова правило не применяется
африке
Для этого слова правило не применяется
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at Task10.main(Task10.java:22)** - это строка System.out.println(words[i]);

О чем это говорит? Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте не `next()`, а `nextLine()`. И в цикле надо писать не `<=`, а строго меньше, потому что в массиве из *n* элементов последний элемент имеет индекс *n-1*. Кстати, лучше код вставлять не скрином, а текстом с 4 пробелами в начале каждой строки.

Comment: Интересно. А в чем разница между next() и nextLine()? Я думал, next() - это универсальная вещь

Comment: `nextLine()` читает всю строку, а `next()` - только то что до пробела.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) twollingchar, как здесь можно поставить лайк за ответ?

Comment: Сейчас я его оформлю, и можно будет поставить лайк. Никак не отучу себя писать ответы в комментах.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {` мне кажется должно быть так. что бы без ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `next()` считывает символы только до пробела. Чтобы считать всю строку, надо использовать `nextLine()`.

А еще я вижу недочет в логике, вот здесь:

```
if (words[i].contains(zhiRight) | words[i].contains(shiRight)) {
    System.out.println("Правильно!");
} else if (words[i].contains(zhiWrong) | words[i].contains(shiWrong)) {
    System.out.println("Неправильно! Жи/Ши пиши с буквой 'и'");
} else
    System.out.println("Для этого слова правило не применяется");
}
```

Сначала проверяется наличие правильного написания, и нам выведет "Правильно" даже если там есть неправильное. Проверьте на слове "жыжи". Надо поменять местами первое условие со вторым.

Также вместо `|` здесь лучше использовать `||`, чтобы избежать лишних вычислений (`a() || b()` не вызовет `b()` если `a()` вернуло `true`).

Comment: @codor01 используй, как шпаргалку или выучи наизусть, как таблицу умножения [логические выражения](https://ibb.co/qgB1Lmb).